# Rust: Generic 'within epsilon' trait for Nums

Tags: generics, rust

I'd like to be able to create a function which I can call on Floats or Complex types which returns true when they are within a specified distance from each other.

This is the closest I got, which of course does not cover Compelx numbers:

```
fn eq_within_epsilon<F: Float>(a: F, b:F, eps: F) -> bool {
    F::abs(a - b) < eps
}
```

I attempted to expand the definition abit, like this, to cover all `Num`:

```
trait EqWithinEpsilon {
    fn eq_within_epsilon<T: Num>(a: T, b:T, eps: T) -> bool;
}

impl EqWithinEpsilon for dyn Float {
    fn eq_within_epsilon<T: Num>(a: T, b: T, eps: T) -> bool {
        T::abs(a - b) < eps
    }
}
```

but I get the error:

```
the trait cannot be made into an object because it uses `Self` as a type parameter
```

Is there any way I can do this.

And just in case it comes up, I am using the following crates:

```
num-complex = "0.4.0"
num-traits = "0.2.15"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing a method for `dyn Trait` is almost never what you want. It doesn't implement the method for all types that implement the trait, but rather on the trait itself.

Usually you would need a blanket implementation (`impl<F: Float> EqWithEpsilon for F`), but in this case it will not work. You need a trait that is common to both `Complex` and floats. You can write your own:

```rust
trait ComplexFloat: Num {
    type Real: Float;
    fn abs(self) -> Self::Real;
}

// We cannot use a blanket implementation because of coherence.
impl ComplexFloat for f32 {
    type Real = Self;
    fn abs(self) -> Self::Real { self.abs() }
}
impl ComplexFloat for f64 {
    type Real = Self;
    fn abs(self) -> Self::Real { self.abs() }
}

impl<F: Float> ComplexFloat for Complex<F> {
    type Real = F;
    fn abs(self) -> Self::Real { self.norm() }
}

fn eq_within_epsilon<F: ComplexFloat>(a: F, b: F, eps: F::Real) -> bool {
    F::abs(a - b) < eps
}
```

If you use the very last version of `num_traits`, 0.4.2 (it wasn't even released to the playground yet, at the time of writing), you can use a ready trait: [`ComplexFloat`](https://docs.rs/num-complex/0.4.2/num_complex/trait.ComplexFloat.html).